# Does Wing also developed the ability to transmute his aura into electricity?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In episode 28 of HxH 2011, Wing extends his aura into a piece of paper and easily cuts through the tin can. By the look of it, the strengthen paper seems to have some "touch" on it. It looks similar to Killua's ability to transmute his aura into electricity.

The image below shows the scene on ***(1)*** HxH 2011, ***(2)*** HxH 1999, ***(3)*** HxH original manga. Which surprisingly the electrical-charged effect can also be seen on the manga, but nothing on the 1999 anime.

[image]

Wing is a typical Enhancer, the closest Nen types he could potentially master besides his main Nen type are Emission and Transmutation. The effect can be easily differentiate as Transmutation type, Killua is the perfect example. But it is practically impossible to develop this technique without spending years of special training and exercise. Is it just an additional "effect" to show the power of Nen during the starting of the arc, or he really had developed this ability?

Comment: I appreciate the research you did on this.  Unfortunately I think the answer is somewhere between "mangaka didn't tell us" and "looks cool".  We don't know his main Nen skill (Hatsu right?). It is worth noting though that Wing is a far more skilled Nen user than he looks and has had some moments that indicate an high degree of skill/ability. (This being one of them). Him having some transmutation ability is probably a given.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to say that that's not actual electricity, but just a visual presentation of Wing imbuing the paper with "energy". A visual flare added as extra clarity for the viewers/readers, who are not yet that familiar with Nen and what all it can do. (Except for the 1999 anime. Even in the manga the "electro-likeness" of the effect is arguable, as it could be seen as more general representations of "energy" or "power" or even a "shock wave".)

I could go on about Wings nen-type, the likelyhood he'd learn transmutation powers, spesifics that would go to learning this spesific power, if Wing would be skilled enough to do this and if he even wanted to. But I think there's a more simple way to conclude that it's not actual electricity.

Apart from the visuals, *it doesn't actually act like electricity* in any way, shape or form.
The paper hardenes, cuts clean through a can and embeds itself to a wall. Nothing in the way it or the objects around it act indicates a presence of electricity. (They don't exactly dismiss it either, but then again, what would be the point of electricity, if it has no use.)